# how to set combo box default value as session logged in user id in sap ui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am using comboBox control in sap ui5. I need to show default logged in user id. How can I achieve so?
This default user id is the part of odata service. For example I have 10 data(INC0001 to INC0010). If user INC0004 logged in then by default I want to show that in the comboBox. I am getting only first blank right now.

XML Code :

```
<Select id="select1" 
        items="{ path: '/UserSet', sorter: { path: 'zuserid' } }" 
        change="handleChange">

     <core:Item text="{zuserid}" key="{zuserid}"/>
     <layoutData>
         <l:GridData span="XL2 L2"/>
     </layoutData>

</Select>
```

Session user in sap ui5:

```
var userId = sap.ushell.Container.getService("UserInfo").getUser().getId();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for this issue.
This will help anyone is looking out for the same.

```
 var oData ={
                recipient :{
                   name :"TCS0001"}};

    var oModel =newJSONModel(oData);
    this.getView().setModel(oModel,"NamedModel");


    <ComboBox id="combo1" selectedKey="{NamedModel>/recipient/name}" items="{ path: '/UserSet', sorter: { path: 'zuserid' } }" change="handleChange">
            <core:Item text="{zuserid}" key="{zuserid}"/>
            <layoutData>
             <l:GridData span="XL3 L3"/>
            </layoutData>
           </ComboBox><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried binding the data in your controller?

```
this.getView().byId("select1").bindItems({
            path: "/UserSet",
            template: new sap.ui.core.Item({
                key: "{zuserid}"
                text: "{zuserid}"
            }),
            events: {
                dataReceived: function () {
                    var userId = sap.ushell.Container.getService("UserInfo").getUser().getId();
                    this.getView().byId("select1").setSelectedKey(userId);
                }.bind(this)
            }
        });
```

The event `dataReceived`is triggered once the data is received and at that point it is possible to set the selected key of your `ComboBox`as @Jorg proposes in the reaction above.

Comment: Hi KristoffDT, I have used your suggested code but still no luck. Getting dropdown data but default value hasn't come.

Comment: Hey Ram, is any of the retrieved values equal to `zuserid`?

Kr, Kristoff

Comment: yes, the value I want as default is a part of drop down data as previously mentioned in the scenario.  For example I have 10 data(INC0001 to INC0010). If user INC0004 logged in then by default.

Comment: and `sap.ushell.Container.getService("UserInfo").getUser().getId()` gives u INC0004? Hmm then I don't get it...

Comment: Your console doesn't show an error of something going wrong? You are sure you haven't assigned selectedKey in your xml? You are not setting thee selectedKey in other part of your code?

Comment: No error in the console. I tried in both ways using json model and binding in the xml view as well as using controller code in both the cases default value doesn't come but the drop down records are loading.

Comment: Did you update your XML  by replacing the `Select` you mentioned in your post by `<Select id='select1'/>` ?

Comment: This how I tried but it didn't work.                                                                                                                         
 var oJsonModel = new JSONModel({ loggedinUser: '' });
this.getView().setModel(oJsonModel,"settings");

var userId =sap.ushell.Container.getService("UserInfo").getUser().getId();

oJsonModel.setProperty("/loggedinUser", userId );

//xmlview
<Select id="select1" selectedKey="{settings>/loggedinUser}" .......>
...
...
</Select>

Comment: aaah, I was under the impression you were using the OData-model, not a local JSON-model. could you update your initial question with a more up-to-date version of your code, I'll have a look at it later

Comment: can we use formatter here and put default value in case of empty record? Just a thought

Answer (score 0):

`Select` has a parameter called `selectedKey` you can use for this. Usually this is another model binding but you can do it programmatically as well.

The SDK has an example: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk#/entity/sap.m.Select/sample/sap.m.sample.Select/code

```
            <Select
                forceSelection="false"
                selectedKey="{/SelectedProduct}"
                items="{
                    path: '/ProductCollection',
                    sorter: { path: 'Name' }
                }">
                <core:Item key="{ProductId}" text="{Name}" />
            </Select>
```

Comment: Thanks Jorg for your reply. Here I can see it is separately defined in the JSON model. In my case it is part of drop down list data coming from Odata service. How can I do so I tried creating separate model but still no success.

Comment: There are various ways of doing that. for some good examples please see the walkthrough: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk#/topic/70ef981d350a495b940640801701c409

Comment: I don't know the cause but It's not working. I am able to get the data from odata but default is not working. I have created json model and blinded with selectedKey but no luck.